# How can I equalize raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster

I've got 2 rasters , its seems that 1 has the data equalized (all values from 1-65535 are there) and the 2nd don't .

Is there a process I can run in order to equalize the data in the 2nd raster ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Import the symbology on the incorrect raster from the correct raster. It's the little folder on the top, right of the symbology tab for the layer. If you're in ArcMap the layers in the current map will be available to select otherwise you will have to save the correct one as a layer file to import its symbology.

Comment: What you mean "equalize"? While the rasters share the same value *range* they do not share the same *distribution*. From your first image it's clear one raster has at least one cell with a value from 0 to 6. In the second there are no cells with a value from 1 to 12 - there are 0s and 13s, but nothing between. If by "equalize" you mean *symbolize* the same, @MichaelMiles-Stimson's comment should be an answer. Though I thought there was a limit on the number of unique values you could render, though I think it can be changed in options.

Comment: Your second image shows two different stretch methods. Were both set to the same method (along with everything else) the values in the two rasters would be rendered in the same way. But this is not likely to be possible, because some of the settings are based on the data values. Since they have a different distribution, the standard deviations and other statistics will be different between rasters, preventing an identical stretch (at least with a statistic derived method).

Comment: @ChrisW - Do you mean that the 2nd raster didn't have radiometric correction (Which is why values are missing?!)
Can I do the correction by myself ?

Comment: @ChrisW The left raster has distribution of all values from 1 to 65535 but the 2nd raster don't , How can I make the 2nd raster "stretch" the data so it will have all values ?

Comment: Your question doesn't give any information about or describe the rasters you are working with, so I can't speak to radiometric correction (and don't know much about it to begin with, as I don't *process* much remote sensing data). If this is remote-sensed data and the second raster has no cells with particular values, that means those values simply weren't present to be measured. "Stretching" the data would fundamentally alter it. We need more information about what you're trying to do beyond 'equalize two rasters' - what are they/do the values depict and what are you comparing?